Deployment Fails for Google Cloud Run Service Due to Quota Exceeded in Specific Region
I am facing an issue when deploying a Google Cloud Run service. The deployment works in some regions but fails in others, specifically with the following error message.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=8, message=Could not create or update Cloud Run service function-name-dev-us-east1. Project failed to initialize in this region due to quota exceeded.

The same deployment code works successfully in other regions but fails in another regions.
Checked quota usage in the Google Cloud Console under "IAM & Admin" -> "Quotas". No apparent overages found.
What specific quotas should I check for Cloud Run services that might be causing this issue?

Service Cloud Run Admin API quotas are customer modifiable at Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Quotas

They have both default and regional values

Increasing quotas more than the default requires a quota increase request by the customer


When a function consumes all of an allocated resource, the resource becomes unavailable until the quota is refreshed or increased. This may mean that your function and all other functions in the same project will not work until then. when one of the resources is over quota and the function cannot execute.
To increase quotas above the defaults listed here, go to the Cloud Console > IAM & Admin > Quotas and select Cloud Run Admin API, select the quotas you want to modify, click EDIT QUOTAS, supply your user information if prompted, and enter the new quota limit for each quota you selected.
Quota may be exceeded for limits and request example:

Instance limit per region

Job run requests per minute per region

Read requests per minute per region

Write requests per minute per region



Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, your recommendations didn't help. Quotas looks fine, each region has at least 10 instances available.

then it might a issue can you create a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue. If you have paid  support try create an issue

Also once check this it ight be helpfull https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/Google-Cloud-Build-throwing-quota-error/td-p/608638
